# Django error en el create view despues de un method post

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

tengo un problema despues de un method post en una pagina web solo se recarga y no tira error ni genera nada en la base de datos, les paso mi codigo si me pueden dar una mano!

```
class CrearEntradaView(CreateView):
        template_name="entrada/crear_entrada.html"
        form_class= CrearEntradaForm
        success_url = reverse_lazy('entrada_app:entry-lista')
```

esta es la vista

```
from django import forms
from .models import Entry

class CrearEntradaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Form definition for CrearEntradaForm."""

    class Meta:
        """Meta definition for CrearEntradaFormform."""

        model = Entry
        fields = ('__all__')
```

esto es el form para el metodo post

```
class Entry(TimeStampedModel):
    #modelo para las publicaciones
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    
    title = models.CharField('Titulo', max_length = 200 )
    resume = models.TextField('Resumen')
    content = RichTextUploadingField('Contenido')
    public = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    image = models.ImageField(
        'Imagen',
        upload_to='Entry',
    )
    portada = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    in_home = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    #para el posicionamiento en la busqueda de pagina
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False , max_length=300)
```

este el modelo para la base de datos

```
{% extends "entrada/base_entrada.html" %}
{% load  static %}

{% block content %}

{% include "includes/header.html" %}
<!--bloque crear entrada-->

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-x">
      <h1 class="cell">Registro de entrada</h1>
      <form class="cell grid-x grid-margin-x" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data" >{% csrf_token %}
          <div class="medium-6 cell">
                <label>titulo:
                    {{form.title}}
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="medium-6 cell">
                  <label>resumen:
                    {{form.resume}}
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="medium-6 cell">
                  <label>contenido:
                    {{form.content}}
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="medium-6 cell">
                  <label>categoria:
                    {{form.category}}
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="medium-12 cell">
                  <label>tag:
                    {{form.tag}}
                  </label>  
                </div>

                <div class="medium-12 cell">
                  <label>publico:
                    {{form.public}}
                  </label>  
                </div>

                <div class="medium-12 cell">
                  <label>portada:
                    {{form.portada}}
                  </label>  
                </div>

                <div class="medium-12 cell">
                  <label>Inicio:
                    {{form.in_home}}
                  </label>  
                </div>

                <div class="medium-12 cell">
                  <button type="submit" class=" success button">Guardar</button>
                </div>
                
              </label>
            </div>
      </form>
</div>

<!--bloque crear entrada-->

{% include "includes/footer.html" %}

{% endblock content %}
```

y este es el html

```
#
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "entrada_app"

urlpatterns = [
    path(
        'entradas/', 
        views.EntryListView.as_view(),
        name='entry-lista',
    ), 
     path(
        'entrada/<slug>/', 
        views.EntryDetailView.as_view(),
        name='entry-detail',
    ), 
    path(
        'create-entrada',
        views.CrearEntradaView.as_view(),
        name='crear-entrada',
    )
]
```

este es el archivo de las url

la verdad ya probe de todo pero teoricamente no estaria mal asi que nose cual seria el error
si alguien me da una ayuda se lo agradeceria mucho!
###################################################################################################

Comment: podrías mostrar también tu archivo de urls, por favor.

Comment: Listo ahi lo agregue

Answer (score 0):

Revisaría si el HTML se tegenera con los input correctos. Por otro lado quizás sea mejor utilizar el método post que el propio Createview ofrece.

**Ejemplo:**

```
class BookCreateView(CreateView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {'form': BookCreateForm()}
        return render(request, 'books/book-create.html', context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = BookCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            book = form.save()
            book.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('books:detail', args=[book.id]))
        return render(request, 'books/book-create.html', {'form': form})
```